# ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, shopping-cart

What I want to do is to check if the same object exists in an ArrayList, and update its quantity by 1. But instead, the code is adding the same Item into the List again, and setting its quantity to 1.

An Item is a class.

```
public class Item{
    public int Id;
    public String Description;
    public int Price;

    public Item(int id)
    {
    this.Id = id;
    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            this.Price = 19.95f;
            this.Description = "Shoes";
            break;
        case 2:
            this.Price = 9.95f;
            this.Description = "Shirt";
            break;
        case 3:
            this.Price = 14.95f;
            this.Description = "Pants";
            break;
    }
}
```

A CartItem class is created to hold the item, along with its quantity

```
public class CartItem{
    public Item itm;
    public int Quantity;

        public CartItem(int itemId)
        {
        this.itm = new Item(itemId)
        this.Quantity=1;
        }

        public boolean Equal(CartItem item)
        {

        final CartItem a = new CartItem(item.Id);
        if (this.itm.Id != a.ProductId)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
}
```

The ShoppingCart class, that stores the list of CartItems, and that contains the method for adding the item into the list.

```
  public ShoppingCart{

        ArrayList<CartItem> Items = new ArrayList<CartItem>();

        public void AddItem(int productId)
        {
        CartItem newItem = new CartItem(productId);

          if (Items.equals(newItem))
          {
            for (CartItem item:Items)
            {
                  if (item.Equal(newItem))
                  {
                    item.Quantity++;
                    return;
            }
          }

          else
          {
            newItem.Quantity = 1;
            Items.add(newItem);
          }
        }
  }
```

When I'm adding an item to the cart, its repeating the same item into the list instead of updating its quantity. The whole problem is because, my code fails to check if the same Item exists in CartItem list, in the ShoppingCart class.

Books, 1
Books, 1
Books, 1

Instead of the desired output

Books, 3